# What is the runtime complexity of this method?

Tags: java

I have an assignment for school to write a deque using linked list in Java and all the methods should be O(1). I was able to acomplish this for all of my methods except for the one that suppose to remove an item from the back of the queue (or at least I think it's not o(1), I am not sure). Can you please tell me if this is O(1), and if it's not, how do I make it O(1)?

```
public Item dequeueBack() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("list is empty");

        Item val = last.value;
        last = last.prev; // set last to be the item before the last
        if(last == null)
            first = null;
        else
            last.next = null;
        size--;
        return val;
```

Comment: What do you think it's runtime complexity is? --- A remark on you code: I would highly recommend to skip the opening and closing parentheses around one-line `if`- ,`else`-, `for`-,... statements. This can lead to nasty and hard to find bugs.

Comment: I thought the runtime complexity is O(n) but I am not sure. We learned in class that worst case time complexity for removing an item from the end of a linked list is O(n) but the implementation was very different and used a for loop. This is way I am confused. I knew that using a for loop will for sure not get me to where I need to be but I don't know if my implementation does. And thank you for your remark.

Comment: For a runtime-complexitiy of `O(n)`, one needs either a loop or a recursion. The presented algorithm has neither. Thus, the presented algorithm has a runtime-complexity of `O(1)`. It is true that removing from the end in a singly-linked list takes `O(n)`. In a doubly-linked list with a `tail`-reference, however, it is `O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation, I understand this very well now. I appreciate your help!